# Can stringstream parse something like this?

Tags: c++, stl

I have strings of data that look like this:

```
b = bool
i = int
sINT: = string whose length is INT followed by a : then the string
m = int message id.
```

Example:

```
m133s11:Hello Worldi-57989b0b1b0
```

This would be:

```
Message ID 133
String 'Hello World' length 11
int -57989
bool false
bool true
bool false
```

Is there something in STL that could easily parse this?

Comment: `find` and `substr` will do the trick, but not easily; [boost spirit](http://boost-spirit.com/home/) will do it easily, but it is not part of the standard library.

Comment: You don't need find, because you know how long is actually parsed token. This is a LL(0) grammar and you can just write a recursive parser - STL is not needed.

Comment: I guess I'd better just do it myself then.

Comment: @rubenvb Who said anything about reading a file?

Comment: @RafałRawicki how did you quickly map the parsing problem to the specific grammars ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yep:

```
std::stringstream   data("m133s11:Hello Worldi-57989b0b1b0");
while(parse(data))
{
   // 1 item was correctly removed from the stream
}

std::istream& parse(std::istream& data)
{
    char format;
    data >> format;

    switch(format)
    {
        case 'i':   int value;  data >> value;break;
        case 'm':   int id;     data >> id;   break;
        case 'b':   bool value; data >> value; break;
        case 's':
        {
            std::size_t   size;
            char          x = '0';
            data >> size >> x;
            if ((!data) || (x != ':'))
            {   // Something went wrong
                data.setstate(std::ios_base::iostate::badbit);
            }
            else
            {
                std::string  value(size, ' ');
                data.read(&value[0], size);
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    return data;
}
```

Comment: I guess I should put this in a while loop though, I want to go through the whole thing.

Comment: How do I keep track of where I am so I can parse each token sequentially?

Comment: @Milo: See updated code (look at the while loop and the return type and the fail state setting `setstate()`).

Answer (score 0):

Not directly. Given the complexity of it, unless you want to grab it all as a string and splice based on context, I'd say you're best off using [boost::regex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/regex/doc/html/index.html) to search for your patterns.